# Change row in pandas to column titles

Tags: python, pandas

Very new to Python/Pandas and this is my first project. As this is my first post on Stackoverflow, I apologize if this is not formatted correctly, or this is already answered. I have searched and could not find this specific case. I have imported into pandas.

Original:

[image: Img]

I then do:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[3]
df = df.ix[4:]
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Corrected columns:

[image: Img2]

But the top left cell is "3". I would prefer if it was blank, or "Index". How could I amend this? I feel I got most of the way there!

Comment: Show us import line - `read_csv` or `read_table`?  Both have *skiprows* argument.

Comment: Try `df.columns = df.iloc[3].data`

Comment: Here is the import line;

    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_excel('http://website.xls', sep = ",", header = None)
    df.columns = df.iloc[3]
    df = df.ix[4:]
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

@Parfait

Comment: Ok, apologies, that is a total mess. I need to work out what mini-Markdown formatting is. I will try to come back and clean it up.

Comment: Use *skiprows* of [read_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html): `df = pd.read_excel('website.xls', skiprows=3)`

Answer (score 2):

using
`df.columns.name = ''` or
`df.columns.name = None` or
`del df.columns.name`
I prefer the third.